# How serializable isolation works in Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, transactions

As far as I understand, this mode should perform transactions sequentially.
I wrote an example that executes 2 transactions in parallel and expected one of them to have an error. But it didn't happen. Help me understand what I'm wrong about.

Here examples using python with psycopg2

transaction1.py:

```
cursor.execute("START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;")
cursor.execute("SELECT balance FROM customers WHERE name = '1'")
print(cursor.fetchall())

time.sleep(10)

cursor.execute("COMMIT")
```

transaction2.py:

```
cursor.execute("START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;")
cursor.execute("UPDATE customers SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE name = '1'")
# I expected here error
cursor.execute("COMMIT")
```

I run transaction1, then transaction 2, expecting transaction 2 to return an error, but it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

The isolation level is called “serializable”, not “serialized”. That means that transactions are not serialized. Rather, you get a guarantee that there is a way to serially execute the same transactions so that they would end up with the same result.

In your case, you get the same result as if the first transaction had completed before the second one started, even though in reality it committed later. Hence there is an equivalent serial execution, and there is no conflict.